# Trying to Fill a Rectangle Object with a JPEG in Java

Tags: java, image, jpeg, fill

I am working on a class project to recreate a Flappy Bird clone on PC. I have this code so far (below) however I would like to replace the red rectangle "bird" with a JPEG of a penguin. Any ideas on how to go about this? I have researched online but cannot seem to get it right; I have never done 2D graphic work in Java. Thank you!

```
package flappyBird;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FlappyBird implements ActionListener, MouseListener, 
KeyListener
{

public static FlappyBird flappyBird;

public final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

public Renderer renderer;

public Rectangle bird;

public ArrayList<Rectangle> columns;

public int ticks, yMotion, score;

public boolean gameOver, started;

public Random rand;

public FlappyBird()
{
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);

    renderer = new Renderer();
    rand = new Random();

    jframe.add(renderer);
    jframe.setTitle("Flappy Bird");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    jframe.addMouseListener(this);
    jframe.addKeyListener(this);
    jframe.setResizable(false);
    jframe.setVisible(true);

    bird = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2 - 10, HEIGHT / 2 - 10, 20, 20);
    columns = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    addColumn(true);
    addColumn(true);
    addColumn(true);
    addColumn(true);

    timer.start();
}

public void addColumn(boolean start)
{
    int space = 300;
    int width = 100;
    int height = 50 + rand.nextInt(300);

    if (start)
    {
        columns.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH + width + columns.size() * 300, HEIGHT - height - 120, width, height));
        columns.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH + width + (columns.size() - 1) * 300, 0, width, HEIGHT - height - space));
    }
    else
    {
        columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size() - 1).x + 600, HEIGHT - height - 120, width, height));
        columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size() - 1).x, 0, width, HEIGHT - height - space));
    }
}

//Column Color
public void paintColumn(Graphics g, Rectangle column)
{
    g.setColor(new Color (112,128,144));
    g.fillRect(column.x, column.y, column.width, column.height);
}

public void jump()
{
    if (gameOver)
    {
        //Creates Bird
        bird = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2 - 10, HEIGHT / 2 - 10, 20, 20);
        columns.clear();
        yMotion = 0;
        score = 0;

        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);

        gameOver = false;
    }

    if (!started)
    {
        started = true;
    }
    else if (!gameOver)
    {
        if (yMotion > 0)
        {
            yMotion = 0;
        }

        yMotion -= 10;
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    int speed = 10;

    ticks++;

    if (started)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++)
        {
            Rectangle column = columns.get(i);

            column.x -= speed;
        }

        if (ticks % 2 == 0 && yMotion < 15)
        {
            yMotion += 2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++)
        {
            Rectangle column = columns.get(i);

            if (column.x + column.width < 0)
            {
                columns.remove(column);

                if (column.y == 0)
                {
                    addColumn(false);
                }
            }
        }

        bird.y += yMotion;

        for (Rectangle column : columns)
        {
            if (column.y == 0 && bird.x + bird.width / 2 > column.x + column.width / 2 - 10 && bird.x + bird.width / 2 < column.x + column.width / 2 + 10)
            {
                score++;
            }

            if (column.intersects(bird))
            {
                gameOver = true;

                if (bird.x <= column.x)
                {
                    bird.x = column.x - bird.width;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (column.y != 0)
                    {
                        bird.y = column.y - bird.height;
                    }
                    else if (bird.y < column.height)
                    {
                        bird.y = column.height;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (bird.y > HEIGHT - 120 || bird.y < 0)
        {
            gameOver = true;
        }

        if (bird.y + yMotion >= HEIGHT - 120)
        {
            bird.y = HEIGHT - 120 - bird.height;
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }

    renderer.repaint();
}

public void repaint(Graphics g)
{
    //Background
    g.setColor(new Color (176,224,230));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    //Ground under bar
    g.setColor(new Color (0,139,139));
    g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 120, WIDTH, 120);

    //Bar above ground
    g.setColor(new Color(100,149,237));
    g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 120, WIDTH, 20);

    //Cube color
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(bird.x, bird.y, bird.width, bird.height);

    for (Rectangle column : columns)
    {
        paintColumn(g, column);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 100));

    if (!started)
    {
        g.drawString("Dare to try?", 75, HEIGHT / 2 - 50);
    }

    if (gameOver)
    {
        g.drawString("You died!", 100, HEIGHT / 2 - 50);
    }

    if (!gameOver && started)
    {
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(score), WIDTH / 2 - 25, 100);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    flappyBird = new FlappyBird();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    jump();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        jump();
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drawImage()` Method of the Graphics object:

```
g.drawImage(yourImage,xPos,yPos,null);
```

Comment: I tried this but it still hasn't worked... I used
      g.drawImage(image.png, bird.x, bird.y, null);
Any advice?